# Macbook Air M1 2021: How to enable virtualization for VMware Fusion 12

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to enable virtualization on my MacBook air (M1) 2021. Is there a way I can check if VMX is enabled so I can download Ubuntu?

Entering `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features` does not work.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1):

VMware Fusion is not yet available for Apple Silicon.

Have a look at: [Fusion on Apple Silicon: Progress Update](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2021/04/fusion-on-apple-silicon-progress-update.html)

Comment: Right now, you options are UTM [see https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/72081-utm-virtual-machine-on-m1-mac/ ] or Parallels [https://www.parallels.com/blogs/parallels-desktop-apple-silicon-mac/ ] Both require you to install an ARM build of the OS to be virtualised - https://kb.parallels.com/uk/125375/